# Cannot launch Unity Game Engine on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: games

After installing [Unity Game Engine](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/), I tried to run it by its launcher but no any window appears. Then, I tried to run it in the terminal and got the following error message.

```
$ ./Unity
./Unity: /opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Tools/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20)
./Unity: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20: symbol gpgrt_lock_lock, version GPG_ERROR_1.0 not defined in file libgpg-error.so.0 with link time reference
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

go to this path 
Unity/Editor/Data/Tools/libgpg-error.so.0
and remove 
libgpg-error.so.0

Comment: This also fixes the problem launching on Ubuntu 17.04.